# Send custom data with dropzone.js on each File Upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone in my Code Igniter Project.

With every drag of a file, dropzone creates an ajax request and my files is getting stored on the server too. But now, my requirement is that I want to send additional data (**DYNAMIC**) alongside the file.
With the use of params, Only static datas can be sent, but the data I want to send will be changing everytime.

This is how my code looks:

```
<script>
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  Dropzone.options.attachment = {
        init: function(){
          this.on('removedfile',function(file){
            // console.log('akjsdhaksj');
            var fileName = file.name;
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "<?php echo BASE_URL.'index.php/admin/mail_actions/deleteFile' ?>",
              data: "id="+fileName,
              dataType: 'html'
            });
          });
        },
        // params: {
        // customerFolder: $('#toValue').substr(0, toValue.indexOf('@')),
        // },
        dictDefaultMessage:"Click / Drop here to upload files",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        dictRemoveFile:"Remove",
        maxFiles:3,
        maxFilesize:8,
  }

$(function(){

  var uploadFilePath = "<?php echo BASE_URL.'index.php/admin/mail_actions/uploadFile' ?>";
  var myDropzone     = new Dropzone("div#attachment", { url: uploadFilePath});

});
</script>
```

Anyway I can achieve it?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

I got it.
This is what I had to use

```
myDropzone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){
    formData.append('userName', 'bob');
});
```

Comment: i tried using this but no luck..and where to add this code? in init ?

Comment: How have you defined your dropzone? Without a snippet its hard to answer. Create a fiddle

Comment: it is sending but not understanding the way it is sending.Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

sss

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

Comment: Try remove the `sending` method when creating the `dropzone instance`, and bind the sending method using `on`

Comment: what is username and bob ? is those are form fields ?

Comment: yes, thats just an example, that will be your custom form datas

Comment: if my input name is first_name & last_name , i need to pass like this na formData.append('first_name', 'last_name'); ? correct me if am wrong..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134592/discussion-between-abhinav-and-shiva).

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you so much! After hours this solved all my problems :)

Comment: @Shiva, is it possible to do something similar to what you had presented in the fiddle but in regard to multiple file uploads? I want to send multiple images that I can set for each one of them a title attribute. Is that possible?

Comment: If you are using flask and you are adding a custom event handler like a button press to upload, this works like a charm. You have to do `request.form['userName']` to go get the value `"bob"`. Using some JavaScript You can maybe go ahead and append more to the `.formData` and get amazing results using Dropzone.

Answer (score 29):

Abhinav has the right and working answer I only want to give a second option to use it in the options object (for example if you have multiple Dropzone sections on one page.)

```
myDropzone.options.dropzoneDivID = {
    sending: function(file, xhr, formData){
        formData.append('userName', 'Bob');
    }
};
```

Comment: I gave your answer an upvote since it shows that there is more than one way to implement this feature

Comment: how do you put variable outside dropzone to the form data append?

Answer (score 13):

In case you have a nested payload object - e.g. to add a name to your file and your api only accepts something like this

```
{
    someParameter: {
        image: <my-upload-file>,
        name: 'Bob'
    }
}
```

your dropzone setup would look like this

```
var myDropzone     = new Dropzone("div#attachment", { 
    url: uploadFilePath,
    paramName: 'someParameter[image]'
});

myDropzone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){
    formData.append('someParameter[image]', file);
    formData.append('someParameter[userName]', 'bob');
});
```

I only added this as there was no example for nested parameters documented since now.

Answer (score 2):

i was using JQuery and this is how worked for me :

```
           $("#dZUpload").dropzone({
                url: "ajax/upload_img_ben.php",
                success: function (file, response) {
                    var imgName = response;
                    file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
                    console.log("Successfully uploaded :" + imgName);
                },
                error: function (file, response) {
                    file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
                },
                sending: function(file, xhr, formData){
                    formData.append('id', '5');
                }
            });
```