# How to send csrf token in dropzone upload post via javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter project and when I enable CSRF protection in config file and added csrf token hidden field in all forms site working fine but due to this I am facing one problem i.e. "The action you have requested is not allowed" while uploading images using dropzone.

**How to pass the csrf token in dropzone js?**

When I upload image in dropzone box it gives error:

> The action you have requested is not allowed.

```
<div class="dropzone clsbox" id="mydropzone">
</div>  

$("div#mydropzone").dropzone({                      
  url: "/riftraff/insert_product_phase_final",
  headers: {
    'X-CSRFToken': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
  }                                                             
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that dropzone accepts the "headers" parameter?

Comment: No, I am not sure then how to send the csrf token in dropzone request?

Comment: @preeti then look at the Dropzone documentation???

Comment: it seems you can http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-headers

Comment: have a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073878/send-custom-data-with-dropzone-js-on-each-file-upload. you can send csrf token in form data also.

Answer (score 4):

```js
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#mydropzone", {
  url: "/riftraff/insert_product_phase_final"
}); 

myDropzone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {
  formData.append('<token_name>', '<token_value>');
});
```